# Prolog defining an ":" operator

Tags: prolog, operators

I have several predicates that have the form of flight/3

```
flight( new_york, boston,
     [ 9:00 /   9:40 / zz765 / everyday,
      16:10 / 16:55 / emi666 / monday ] ).
```

So I need to define the ":" operator.
Which is the following

```
:- op( 50, xfx, :).
```

Now, the results are extremelly strange.

1) If I compile just 1 time I get this:

```
X = [9:((0/9):(40/zz765/everyday)),
     16:((10/16):(55/emi666/monday))]
```

2) If I compile it more than 2 times:

```
 X = [9:0/9:40/zz765/everyday,16:10/16:55/emi666/monday]
```

Which this is crazy!!!!
I though it should have been

```
:- op(400, xfx, :).
```

So it has the same preceden of / 
But if I compile it twice I get syntax errors on my flight/3 predicates.

At the end, I need associativity like this: (becuase I will be doing operation with those time).

```
[ (9:00) /   (9:40) / zz765 / everyday, ]
```

How do I do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this data coming from? Do you have any control over its format?

Answer (score 1):

The common priority and specifier for infix `:` as defined in ISO/IEC 13211-2:2000 is:

```
:- op(600, xfy, :).
```

Unless you want to break a lot of programs, stick to that definition.

The problem you got was the following.

1. You compiled `flight/2` with standard operators.
2. You changed priority and specifier to unusual values.
3. Now, the toplevel printed terms that otherwise do not need any extra parentheses with your non-standard operator. Yes, this looks crazy, but what do you expect if you change basic syntax in a running program!

So, always stick to `op(600, xfy, :)`.

Comment: thats not helping me. I need to redefine it. So Do I have to redefine also operations with : ?

Comment: @Alessandroempire: If you are redefining this, then you are in completely uncharted territory! `:` is used for module prefixes, so lots of library code you use will break - or worse: break in very subtle and hard-to-debug ways...

Comment: what If i wont use that operator anywhere else in my code. Actually, I wont use it in my code the : operator. So yes I am breaking code that I wont be using. In this case, can I do it?

Comment: @Alessandroempire: Should you load a single library, you would be in trouble - sometimes.

Comment: how about another way. Define an operator :- op (?, ?, newOp) that associates like I asked. Can it be done. Should i post a new question?